# Problem after renaming wordpress template file

Tags: themes, page-template

After renaming the files of my templates and inside the file with php, it is looking for the old templates. The dropdown is no longer available. Why is this happening and how to fix that?

The only files i modified is the `template-parts` folder inside the child theme. I did not touch the `class-wp-theme.php` where it is the warning.

[image]

Comment: this is a known bug within WordPress 4.9 where WordPress saves the template file name and doesn't gracefully fail when the template is no longer there

Comment: Everything is fixed now, i just needed to wait for some reason.

Comment: To speed up this process you can change your theme's version because its cached with the theme version. Later you can just change it back

Comment: @Wilco okay i will try that, the next time i may come in this problem. I hope  this bug will get fixed though soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have WP-CLI installed, try to run `wp cache flush`

or

you can put this code into your functions.php

```
function fix_template_caching( WP_Screen $current_screen ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $current_screen->base, array( 'post', 'edit', 'theme-editor' ), true ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    if ( ! $theme ) {
        return;
    }
    $cache_hash    = md5( $theme->get_theme_root() . '/' . $theme->get_stylesheet() );
    $label         = sanitize_key( 'files_' . $cache_hash . '-' . $theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    $transient_key = substr( $label, 0, 29 ) . md5( $label );
    delete_transient( $transient_key );
}

add_action( 'current_screen', 'fix_template_caching' );
```

Reference: [Fix for theme template file caching https://gist.github.com/westonruter/6c2ca0e5a4da233bf4bd88a1871dd950](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/6c2ca0e5a4da233bf4bd88a1871dd950)

Hope this helps!

:)